# How to make a Reactjs CRUD table editable?

Tags: reactjs

I am making this dynamic/CRUD table for a project at work. I am stuck at this part of the project where if I press the edit button, I want the data on my table become editable or display an input text field box around my data.

I already set up the skeleton of the edit button but the functionality doesn't work. The `handleRowEdit(product){` row is the part of what is needed in there.

I know to add and delete you have to use the splice and push method.

```
class Books extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {};
this.state.filterText = "";
this.state.products =  [ 
    {
    name: "Jim Hoskins",
    author: "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    genre: "Murder & Mystery",
    dateAdded: "1/18/2015 2:24:12 PM",
    OutofPrint: "False",
    id: 1,
    },

    {
    name: "The Scowrers",
    author: "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    genre: "Murder & Mystery",
    dateAdded: "1/1/2016 4:55:54 AM",
    OutofPrint: "True",
    id: 2,
    },
    ];


this.handleAddEvent = this.handleAddEvent.bind(this);
this.handleRowDel = this.handleRowDel.bind(this);
this.handleRowEdit = this.handleRowEdit.bind(this);
   }


handleRowDel(product) {
      var index = this.state.products.indexOf(product);
      this.state.products.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState(this.state.products);
       };

 handleRowEdit(product){
     this.setState(this.state.products);
        }

  handleAddEvent(e) {
       var id = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)).toString(36);
     var product = {
        id: id,
        name: "",
           author: "",
        dateAdded: "",
        OutofPrint: "",
         }
        this.state.products.push(product);
       this.setState(this.state.products);
      }
```

This is not all the code but like I said, I set up the edit button already, but I don't have the functionality behind it.

Comment: Your problem is probably there : `this.setState(this.state.products);`. setState needs an object representing the modifications you want to do. Also, welcome to StackOverflow ! In the future, please avoid questions with so much code and so few explanation. Try to outline what you're trying to achieve, what's the expected behaviour, and what's the actual one.

Comment: Please edit your question title. Be more specific and related to your main question.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you can set the state as follows:

```
this.state = {
    filterText : "",
    products :  [ 
    {
    name: "Jim Hoskins",
    author: "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    genre: "Murder & Mystery",
    dateAdded: "1/18/2015 2:24:12 PM",
    OutofPrint: "False",
    id: 1,
    },    
    {
    name: "The Scowrers",
    author: "Arthur Conan Doyle",
    genre: "Murder & Mystery",
    dateAdded: "1/1/2016 4:55:54 AM",
    OutofPrint: "True",
    id: 2,
    },
    ]
    };
```

In your event handlers, when you modify the state, you should do so in an immutable way.

```
handleRowDel(product) {
  //quick deep copy. use Immutable.js for better immutable data structures
  let localProducts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.products));
  var index = localProducts.indexOf(product);
  localProducts.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState(localProducts);
}
```

You can change the Add handler in a similar manner.

For the edit handler

```
handleRowEdit(product) {
  //quick deep copy. use Immutable.js for better immutable data structures
  let localProducts = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.products));
  let index =localProducts.findIndex(p=>p.id===product.id);
  localProducts[index] = product;
  this.setState(localProducts);
}
```

Hope this helps!